# Foursquare Redirect Page

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Пытаюсь сделать авторизацию через 4сквэр и в момент когда меня должно редиректнуть это страницу для подтверждения авторизации мне просто возвращается html той страницы на которую меня должно было бы редиректнуть. Как мне попасть на ту страницу из кода?

```
public void authenticate() throws IOException {
    String url  =  "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/4sqr/callback_url&client_id=1DUHD3H1DGL5*********NFSLRDLR";
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    // здесь просто html той страницы на которую должно было бы перекинуть
    System.out.println(content);
}
```

Comment: Это стандартный Apache HttpClient?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да. подозреваю, что это так и не должно было бы работать. Тогда интересует как же правильно вызвать этот реквест?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё правильно, вы с помощью `HttpClient` скачали содержимое `url` и отправили пользователю. А нужно пользователя на этот `url` перенаправить:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String authenticate() {
    String url  =  "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/4sqr/callback_url&client_id=1DUHD3H1DGL5*********NFSLRDLR";
    return "redirect:" + url; 
}
```

Comment: это из контроллера делается я так понимаю, правильно?

Comment: Да, правильно понимаете.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо. Но почему не работает этот стандарт префикса `redirect:` и просто возвращает контатенированную строку.

Comment: все. сделал через `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()`. Работает. Спасибо.